# Solve this integral using the Residue Theorem

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

The integral given is $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(a+bt^2)^{-m} dt$ where $a,b >0, m\in\mathbb{N}$.

According to the Residue Theorem, if $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty,\Im(z)>0}zf(z)=0$ then

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) dt = 2\pi i \sum_{\Im(z)>0} \operatorname{Res}_z(f)$$.
Now first I see that $z(a+bz^2)^{-m} \rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$.

Now I need the the poles of the function which are $\pm\sqrt{-a}/\sqrt{b}=\pm i\sqrt{a/b}$ (not sure if that's correct though). I only need to look at the solution with the positive imaginary part.

For the residue I assumed that the order of the pole is $2$ although I'm not sure about that either. Using the definition of the residue involving the factorial etc. I get $0$?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can get more legible displayed equations by enclosing them in `$$` instead of `$`, and you can get the proper font and spacing for operators like $\operatorname{Res}$ using `\operatorname{Res}`.

Answer (score 6):

The function $(a+bz^2)^{-m}$ has exactly two poles, located at $\pm\sqrt{\frac ab}i$. Both of them are poles of order $m$, and only one of them has imaginary part greater than $0$, which is $\sqrt{\frac ab}i$.

Let $\lambda=\sqrt{\frac ab}$. Then$$a+bz^2=b\left(\frac ab+z^2\right)=b(z+\lambda i)(z-\lambda i),$$and therefore$$\left(a+bz^2\right)^{-m}=b^{-m}(z+\lambda i)^{-m}(z-\lambda i)^{-m}.$$When $z$ is near $\lambda i$, you have\begin{align}(z+\lambda i)^{-m}&=\bigl(2\lambda i+(z-\lambda i)\bigr)^{-m}\\&=(2\lambda i)^{-m}\left(1+\frac{z-\lambda i}{2\lambda i}\right)^{-m}\\&=(2\lambda i)^{-m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2\lambda i)^n}\binom{m+n-1}{m-1}(z-\lambda i)^n,\end{align}since$$|w|<1\implies(1-w)^{-m}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{m+n-1}{m-1}w^n.$$Therefore$$(a+bz^2)^{-m}=(2b\lambda i)^{-m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2\lambda i)^n}\binom{m+n-1}{m-1}(z-\lambda i)^{n-m}.$$So,\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=\lambda i}(a+bz^2)^{-m}&=\frac{(2b\lambda i)^{-m}(-1)^{m-1}}{(2\lambda i)^{m-1}}\binom{2m-2}{m-1}\\&=b^{-m}(2\lambda i)^{1-2m}(-1)^{m-1}\binom{2m-2}{m-1}\\&=(-1)^{m-1}\frac{2\lambda ib^{-m}}{2^{2m}\lambda^{2m}(-1)^m}\binom{2m-2}{m-1}\\&=-\frac{\lambda i}{2^{2m-1}a^m}\binom{2m-2}{m-1}.\end{align}It follows that your integral is equal to$$\frac{\pi\lambda}{2^{2m-2}a^m}\binom{2m-2}{m-1}.$$

Comment: That's what makes the Residue Theorem so great - it makes seemingly impossible integrals both simple and fun.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Indeed.